# Why wget wall clock time much higher than download time?

Tags: linux, performance, shell, wget

```
wget --page-requisites --span-hosts --convert-links --adjust-extension --execute robots=off --user-agent Mozilla --random-wait https://www.invisionapp.com/inside-design/essential-steps-designing-empathy/
```

The command above provides the following time stats:

```
Total wall clock time: 35s
Downloaded: 248 files, 39M in 4.2s (9.36 MB/s)
```

This website takes about 5 seconds to download and display all files on a hard refresh in the browser.

Why is the wall clock time **significantly longer** than the download time and is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  Please use the search function.  You can find similar questions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430810/wget-download-with-multiple-simultaneous-connections and several other places in the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: Thanks. I did search, but I believe the question is different. If `total_download_time` represents the total time spent downloading the files, then this matches the speed of the browser, *which would be ideal*, however, `wall_clock - total_download_time = 35s - 4.2s = 30.8s` seems like a rather excessive time to write 248 files with cumulative size of **39M** to disk.

I've also tried removing `--convert-links` and adding `--no-clobber` to the wget command and running `wget_command & wget_command` in the terminal to spawn multiple processes to parallelize the download, but no success.

Comment: A better question might be "What tool should I use instead of wget".  Wget is single-threaded.

Comment: @ChristopherHostage Thanks. I may ask a new question. But even with wget as a single-threaded program, shouldn't launching multiple instances `wget_command  & wget_command` (which is from the article you linked that I found before and tried) with `--no-clobber` effectively achieve parallel downloads? Because `--no-clobber` checks if any file (or even part of a file) has been downloaded and should skip it and move on to the next file that actually needs to be downloaded. But my results don't achieve this, which is why I asked this question. And `30.8s` seems like a long time to write `39M`.